# Django Image Upload Always Fails, form is never valid

Tags: python, django, image, forms

A simple image upload to the default django db never completes. The error seems to suggest that something is going wrong with the image field, as where my views.py prints form.errors, it returns

image

This field is required.

Here is my code, I've only uploaded what I think could be affecting it.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_images")
     slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug = slugify(self.name)
       super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from shareIt.models import Image

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter an image name")
    image = forms.ImageField()
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ('name', 'image')
```

**views.py**

```
def uploadImage(request):

if request.method== 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return images(request)
    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = ImageForm()

contextdict = {"form": form}
return render(request, 'uploadImage.html', contextdict)
```

**uploadImage.html**

```
<html>
<form id="upload" action="/share/images/upload" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" name="submit", value="upload image" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `enctype` attribute to the `<form>` tag:

```
<form id="upload" action="/share/images/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I didn't think it was a multipart form as it was all on the one page, but I guess it's something to do with using request.POST and request.FILES, right?

Comment: Yeah, it has nothing to do with multiple pages. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is always required when you're uploading files (this isn't specific to django).

Answer (score 0):

When you use model form you don't have to type:

```
name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter an image name")
image = forms.ImageField()
slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

You already have that in your model. You only need this:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('name', 'image')
```